# is "Object();" a predefined function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

I come across code such as "personObj=new Object();" where a new object called personObj is being defined. What I'm trying to find out is whether Object() is a prefined function in javascript, because I understand by using the mentioned code, a instance of a class is being formed but in the example code where I'm studying from, the class Object() is not being defined anywhere, so I was wondering if Object() was a predefined function in javascript and whether I can be directed to some online resources, as all that shows up in google when I try to find Object() are articles in general javascript object oriented programming.

Comment: Just to be technically correct: There exist no classes in JavaScript. What you are referring to is a *constructor function*, i.e. a function that creates an object. Theoretically, every function combined with `new` could be a constructor function. `new Object()` creates a new empty object. The same can be achieved with *object literal notation*: `personObj = {}` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) is predefined in Javascript. The [Javascript documentation at developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) is an excellent resource.

Comment: In particular, he should probably look here: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference (The main page has a lot of options might be sort of confusing to people who are not sure which particular reference thing they want.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, but you are better off using an object literal like this

```
var person = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Object` is built-in.

I find [javascriptkit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/index.shtml) to be a good JavaScript reference, but there are probably plenty of others out there.